# How do I use BootstrapFX in my Maven JavaFX project with FXML?

Tags: java, css, xml, twitter-bootstrap, javafx

Using IntelliJ, I wanted to create a new JavaFX project using BootstrapFX framework in order to improve the look of my app. I thought it would be easy to include it and use it but I couldn't find any documentation online.

The only example I found is this: [Link](https://github.com/kordamp/bootstrapfx) but this doesn't mention anything about settings in the FXML files and controller classes since it does everything in the `start()` method. Can somebody help me? I anticipately apologize for any incorrect thing I could have said since I am new to this.

Comment: There was an [answer which seemed fairly decent that was moderator deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74692724/1155209), I am not sure why.

Comment: The [Idea new project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) provides an option for including BootstrapFX in a project, perhaps try that and see if it helps (I don't know if it will or not in your case).

Comment: @jewelsea I have used that, but I don’t know how to set it in the code. I mean how to actually tell JFX I want to use that framework. The GitHub page shows how to do that from Java code but I would like to do that from the FXML file.

Comment: Yeah that info looks to be in the moderator deleted answer.

Comment: There is a style sheet you get through a static method `BootstrapFX.bootstrapFXStylesheet()` which gets `bootstrapfx.css` out of the bootstrap jar (fxml can reference style sheets so if you extracted it to a file you can also access it that way).  And there is one additional layout class called Panel.  All other usages are just setting style classes, which can also be set in fxml.  There are lots of examples in the [sampler code](https://github.com/kordamp/bootstrapfx/tree/master/subprojects/sampler/src/main), which is mostly bootstrap styled fxml.